# precompiling assets locally gives absolute url for background scss urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I am using heroku for my rails app. And I precompile assets locally and then deploy.
So whenever I run
 `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

my URLs in scss are converted from relative paths to absolute paths in precompiled scss so
`/home.png` is converted to `http://localhost:3000/home.png`

How can I get relative paths in the precompiled files too?

Comment: Please update with a css block where you have an image.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if `config.asset_host` is non-nil. You only need to set it if you're [using a CDN](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#cdns) otherwise, ensure that it's `nil`.